# how to have tags/annotation on interface fields

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking at Mongoose example here

```
import { Schema, Types } from 'mongoose';

// 1. Create an interface representing a document in MongoDB.
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  // Use `Types.ObjectId` in document interface...
  organization: Types.ObjectId;
}

// 2. Create a Schema corresponding to the document interface.
const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  // And `Schema.Types.ObjectId` in the schema definition.
  organization: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization' }
});
```

Schema's constructor takes an object that has dynamic property (all the properties of IUser) and then it has other tags (like `type`, `required`)

How can I create a class that looks like Schema in above example with attributes associated with interface's field

Comment: If you mean the `<IUser>` part then that is a generic type parameter: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: no I mean the Schema has dynamic attributes passed in for example `name`, `email`, `organization` here. How can I do something like this?

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic attribute"? `new Schema` just looks like it takes a normal object to me. There's nothing magic about the format of that object. It's simply the data type that the `Schema` constructor is declared to take. Please edit your question to add details about what you are trying to achieve and maybe we can provide more help.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Alex. I edited the question. Can you help with some code for Schema class that can accept the attributes of the generic type.

Comment: What aspect of this are you trying to replicate? What do you expect to do with the `userSchema` object from your example? Do you simply want to be able to pass in a type and then have the constuctor take an argument take conforms to that type? https://tsplay.dev/WYkG2N

Comment: @Alex thank you again. the other attributes that goes with property such as `type`, `required` etc..

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Just code that actually that does something useful with a schema definition? https://tsplay.dev/NnaRow

Comment: awesome @Alex - please post it as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @Alex - how can I iterate through the property of schema. For example if I do JSON.stringify(schema) I get `required` field per property but not the `type` field.

Comment: I chose to make `type` a class constructor to make it easy to use the `instanceof` operator to check if a value is an instance of some class. `"a string" insanceof String` is `true`. However, functions and classes are not serializable to JSON, so those properties are skipped by `JSON.stringify()`. If you want the schema to be JSON serializable then you will have to come up with different logic and a different format. Like, say, [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I just posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72279183/typescript-access-type-of-interface-property before I saw your comment.